# Why is my docker container not listening to changes in my files

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

So i've been developing this backend on NestJS and Docker using docker-compose also for about 6 months now but never had issues with my docker not listening to my file changes. A few days ago, this started happening and i dont know why.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV development

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN yarn install

ENTRYPOINT ["yarn", "start:dev"]
```

And this is my docker-compose file

```
services:
  api:
    image: cacao-be
    container_name: cacao-be-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app/src
    networks:
      - default
    links:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env
volumes:
  db_data:
  admin_data:
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

This is my package.json which includes the script to start my proyect

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch"
}
```

Here´s also my tsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
},
}
```

And tsconfig.build.json file

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

I've tried running my proyect without docker and it did listen to file changes, but when i run it in docker it stops listening to them. I've verifyed and in both approaches it runs in watch mode.
`Starting compilation in watch mode...`

Also, i've entered to my container via cmd, and checked if files were changing as i modified them, and they did (i could prove that my service was well mounted). So inside the container file changes but it doesnt restart the development

I've set

```
command: npm run start:dev
```

in my docker-compose file, but it didn't work. Cleaning my docker and restarting it also didnt work.

What i expect is that when i save a file, my docker logs restart and apply changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for being late to the party. Actually it's due to the **TypeScript** version. If you upgrade it to `4.9`, then it won't work anymore. Because in `4.9`, they changed how files should be watched, and they're now using FS events instead of legacy polling. You can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#file-watching-now-uses-file-system-events). So if you want to make it work again, use `4.8.4` for now. In your `package.json`, change the `typescript` version like so:

```json
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "~4.8.4",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for telling. Any solutions for using the new version?

Comment: For me, it's WSL.

Comment: If want to working on prev strategy (polling, not file event)
add to tsconfig.json
It works for me
`
// https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#file-watching-now-uses-file-system-events
  // https://www.typescriptlang.org/ko/docs/handbook/configuring-watch.html
 "watchOptions": {
    "watchFile": "dynamicprioritypolling",
    "watchDirectory": "dynamicprioritypolling",
    "fallbackPolling": "dynamicpriority"
  }
`

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here with NestJS services in Docker-compose.
Hot reload stops working few days ago.

Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
  back:
    build: ./back
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: back
    ports: #For health check
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - ./back:/usr/local/app
      - node_modules_back:/usr/local/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - db
```

NestJS scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "ci": "npm run build && npm run format && npm run lint && npm run test && npm audit"
  },
```

Comment: I solve this issue by cloning my project in a WSL Ubuntu 22.04 distro, then NestJS hot reload works again. Explanation is to avoid mixin file systems between Docker distro and your project volume, because WSL 2has this issue. I don't know why it worked...

Comment: So the solution would be to clone my proyect into wsl directory? My coworker is experiencing the same issue and he is working on IOS, while im working on Windows.

Comment: @JuanPedroPontVergés Yes, on Windows, I have cloned my docker-compose project into a \\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\ folder, then I use docker-compose commands from Git Bash on Windows. The purpose is too still use Docker Desktop, but that the files shared between local and containers are on the same kind of file systems.

Comment: Thanks! this worked, but i dont like being forced to move my directory to the wsl

Comment: Is there a way to keep the directory on windows system insteado of wsl?. It brought me more problems than resolved