# Docker container not auto restarting on code save

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container that should be set to recompile and restart when my React project files change, but it rarely does (I haven't noticed a pattern on when it stops restarting). My teammates are using the same container on their machine and haven't experienced the issue. Are there any settings or system limitations that may be causing me issues? I'm running a 2023 MacBook Pro. My docker file is as follows:

```
frontend:
    image: frontend
    profiles:
      - default
      - dev
      - prod
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker-build/frontend/Dockerfile
    environment:
      WATCHPACK_POLLING: "true"
      PORT: 80
      ENVIRONMENT: ${ENVIRONMENT}
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app:rw
    container_name: frontend
    restart: always
    #ports:
    # - "127.0.0.1:3000:3000"
```

RESOLVED: [Why is my docker container not listening to changes in my files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74476459/why-is-my-docker-container-not-listening-to-changes-in-my-files/75273135#75273135)

Comment: "rarely does" -- does it mean it sometimes restarts and sometimes it doesn't? And which OS is your teammate's machine running?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it does, but there really is no pattern I can see. Honestly, it doesn't restart often enough to be statistically significant. 

He's running MacOS 13.5.1 same as me.

Comment: Does the container shut down when it doesn't restart on code change? Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75273135/11317272) may give you useful context.

Comment: @msrumon that seems to have done the trick!